# User Profile Service Application Error

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, service-application

I have Sharepoint Server 2010 Standard installed.
I want to configure the default "User Profile Service Application".
When I click on User Profile Service Application from central admin, it gives following error message:

Error 
An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: d966e250-c3a7-46ce-8661-77c0a08f071a

Date and Time: 3/15/2012 4:51:25 PM

How can I troubleshoot this issue? 
Could someone also give an advise if I should use the default user profile service application or should I create a new one and disable the default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do:

1. Reproduce your error
2. Go in the 14/LOGS of your central administration server
3. Open the log file that is currently in use
4. Perform a search on the CorrelationID (try to use something else than Notepad, best way is to use a SharePoint Log Viewer: http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/)

Then you'll have logs about your errors. Control every lines, correlation ID can regroup many lines.

Comment: There are too many log files in 14/LOGS
How do I know which is the one currently in use?
Sorry, Im new to sharepoint

Comment: You can sort them by modify date in Windows Explorer. Select the one with the timestamp corresponding to your last issue time.

Comment: You can try this PowerShell `Merge-SPLogFile -Correlation 'd966e250-c3a7-46ce-8661-77c0a08f071a' -Path .\log.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are using the June CUs or later. Recently I installed a fresh copy at SP1 and had the same problem. I applied the December CUs and it worked fine.

Be sure you are following this exactly: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx and follow the steps exactly.

M

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, make sure you have set the log level to verbose for the time of reproduction.

You might want to follow this tread as well: [User Profile Sync Service Frustration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31026/user-profile-sync-service-frustration)